# Datadog python api error INFO No agent or invalid configuration file found

Tags: python, python-2.7, datadog

I'm trying to use the datadog api but the initialize method keeps giving the error 'INFO No agent or invalid configuration file found'.

The datadog agent is running:

(PYTHON) daphnepaparis@Daphnes-MBP-2 ~ $ /usr/local/bin/datadog-agent status
Datadog Agent (supervisor) is running all child processes

And the configuration file permissions look alright:

(PYTHON) daphnepaparis@Daphnes-MBP-2 ~ $ ls -l ~/.datadog-agent/datadog.conf
lrwxr-xr-x  1 daphnepaparis  staff  35 Mar 22 12:58 /Users/daphnepaparis/.datadog-agent/datadog.conf -> /opt/datadog-agent/etc/datadog.conf

Original commands I'm running:

In [1]: from datadog import initialize, api

In [2]: options = {'api_key': '***'}

In [3]: initialize(**options)

2017-03-22 13:24:20 INFO No agent or invalid configuration file found

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So from that log line, it appears as though [this `try` is excepting](https://github.com/DataDog/datadogpy/blob/v0.6.x/datadog/util/hostname.py#L51) in the library's `hostname.py`. So either...

- (A) The [hostname line](https://github.com/DataDog/datadogpy/blob/v0.6.x/datadog/util/hostname.py#L53) is where it's excepting, and (weirdly) the
  library requires that a `hostname` option be set in your
  `datadog.conf` file. Maybe worth setting a hostname there if you
  haven't already. Or,
- (B) The [get_config() line](https://github.com/DataDog/datadogpy/blob/v0.6.x/datadog/util/hostname.py#L52) is where it's excepting, and so the
  library isn't able to correctly identify the configuration file
  location (or access it, possibly related to permissions). Based on
  the directory structure in your question, I think you're working on
  an OSX / mac environment, which means the library will be using the
  function `_mac_config_path()` in `config.py` to try to identify the
  configuration path, which from [this line in the function](https://github.com/DataDog/datadogpy/blob/v0.6.x/datadog/util/config.py#L83) would
  make it *seem* as though the library were looking for the
  configuration file in `~/.datadog-agent/agent/datadog.conf` instead
  of the appropriate `~/.datadog-agent/datadog.conf`. Which might be a
  legitimate bug...

So if I were you, and if all this seemed right, I'd try adding a [hostname in the `datadog.conf`](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/blob/5.13.x/datadog.conf.example#L25) to see if that helped, and if it didn't, then I'd try making a `~/.datadog-agent/agent/` directory and copying your `datadog.conf` file there as well, just to see if that got things working.

This answer assumes you are working in an OSX / mac environment, and will likely not be correct otherwise.

If either (A) or (B) are the case, then that's a problem with the library and should be updated--it would be kind of you to open an issue on [the library itself](https://github.com/DataDog/datadogpy) to bring this up so the Datadog team that supports that library can be made aware. I suspect not many people end up this library in OSX / mac environments to begin with, so that could explain all this.

Comment: hey Stephen thanks for your help! the issue was B, once I created the agent directory and copied the conf over everything worked fine. I'll bring it up to the Datadog team. thanks again.

Comment: I received this error while running my code in google cloud function and there I believe, I can  not apply any of the fix mentioned above. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: oooh, not really sure how you'd call on that library from a cloud function, but you can probably reach out to Datadog support to get some guidance on that.

Comment: For anybody looking… I’m on macOS Catalina (10.15.7) and running the Agent locally on my Mac. It reported an invalid API key ("datadog API key ending with PIKEY”) despite it being populated correctly (I double and triple checked). It turned out I needed to explicitly provide the hostname in the datadog.yaml file.